# Writing an macro that checks if a character is alphabetic

Tags: c, algorithm, debugging, macros

I am trying to write macro `IS_ALPHABETIC` that gives a non-zero value if a character is an alphabetic character. In it I am referring to a `IS_LOWER_CASE` macro I defined and the `uppercase` macro I defined earlier.

Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define uppercase(n)  ((n) <= 'Z' && (n) >= ('A') ) 
#define IS_LOWER_CASE(n) ( ((n) >= 'a') && ((n) <= 'z') )

#define IS_ALPHABETIC(n) (uppercase(n) || IS_LOWER_CASE(n) ? (n) : 5)

int main()
{
    char letter = "4";
    printf("%d\n", IS_ALPHABETIC(letter));
}
```

So essentially the `IS_ALPHABETIC` macro is supposed to give the value 5 if the argument is an alphabetic character because it checks it if is a lowercase or uppercase alphabetic character, however it gives 5 each time regardless of the argument.

For example, in my case, I entered 4 so it shouldn't give the value 5. It should only when I enter an alphabetic value.

The `uppercase` and `IS_LOWER_CASE` macros just check whether the argument is uppercase or lowercase, respectively.

I am not 100% sure if I constructed my `IS_ALPHABETIC` macro correctly. What is wrong?

**I am trying to do it strictly using these specific macros.**

Comment: So whats wrong with the standard [`isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha)?

Comment: isalpha is available by including ctype.h

Comment: I will make an edit to my post. I am trying to do it strictly using these specific macros. Thanks though.

Comment: That is a liberal use of brackets you have there. Can I suggest you standardize your encapsulation, it would make the code much easier to read.

Comment: Because it can not assume all characters are arranged without a gap as this character code, such a method is not portable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change:

```
char letter= "4";
```

to:

```
char letter= '4';
```

Also **turn on compiler warnings** (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) - let the compiler catch silly mistakes like this for you and save yourself a lot of time and effort.

Note that you probably want `IS_ALPHABETIC` to return TRUE/FALSE (1/0) instead of n or 5.

And on a matter of programming style, try to be more consistent with naming, formatting, use of parentheses, etc, e.g. here is a cleaned up version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IS_UPPER_CASE(n) ((n) >= 'A' && (n) <= 'Z') 
#define IS_LOWER_CASE(n) ((n) >= 'a' && (n) <= 'z')

#define IS_ALPHABETIC(n) (IS_UPPER_CASE(n) || IS_LOWER_CASE(n))

int main()
{
    char letter = '4';
    printf("%d\n", IS_ALPHABETIC(letter));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But it still returns 5. Any suggestions there?

Comment: @XiJiaopin Did you recompile? With `char letter='A'`, it returns `65` for me, not 5

Comment: @XiJiaopin your letter is `4` then not in [a-z] or [A-Z] then `uppercase(n) || IS_LOWER_CASE(n)` returned false (0) then `IS_ALPHABETIC(letter)` return `5`.if you choose something like ``s`` or another alphabet charachters (in [a-zA-Z]) then its return its ACSII code

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define    IS_UPPER_CASE(n)    (((n) <= 'Z') && ((n) >= 'A')) 
#define    IS_LOWER_CASE(n)    (((n) >= 'a') && ((n) <= 'z'))

#define    IS_ALPHABETIC(n)    (IS_UPPER_CASE(n) || IS_LOWER_CASE(n) ? (n) : 5)

int main()
{
    char letter = 'a';
    printf("%d\n", IS_ALPHABETIC(letter));
}
```

Above is the edited version of your code snippet and it will not return 5 all the times.

char letter = "4";

The above initialization generates a compiler warning as you are trying to initialize a char with an address (of the string "4" and not character 4).

However, for your inputs you might want to print the character if it is an alphabet. But what is going to be printed is the integer value equivalent to the ASCII value of the character.
So, you might try %c instead of %d in the printf() call.